# Button click event does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

### View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<fieldset>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

     <div align="center">

     @{

        @(Html.Telerik().Grid<SmartTrack.Web.DAL.SysUserList>()
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("Index", "User"))
        .Name("UserList")
        .DataKeys(keys => keys
            .Add(c => c.UserName)
            .RouteKey("UserName"))
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.UserName).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(o => o.FirstName).Width(200);
            columns.Bound(o => o.LastName).Width(250);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Active).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled' name='Active' <#=Active? checked='checked' : '' #> />").Width(70).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }); ;


        })
        .Pageable(pagerAction => pagerAction.PageSize(20))
        .Sortable()
        .Selectable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Filterable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:50%;" })
       )
         }
       </div>
       <br/>
       <div align="center">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="btnAdd" type="submit" style="height:40px;width:70px" ">Add</button>
            </td>
            <td>
            <button style="height:40px;width:70px" ">Edit</button>
            </td>
            <td>
            <button style="height:40px;width:70px" ">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>   
       </div>
       </fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Create","User")',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#cuscreate').html(result)
            }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

This view contain a script from which the UserController Create method is call when the add button is clicked

### Control

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SmartTrack.Web.Attributes;
using SmartTrack.Web.Models;
using SmartTrack.Web.DAL;
using Telerik.Web.Mvc;
namespace SmartTrack.Web.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        SMARTTrackerEntities db = new SMARTTrackerEntities();

        //
        // GET: /User/
        [GridAction]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //ViewData["UserGroup"] = DisplayContentEngine.getUserGroupList();

            return View(new GridModel(UserListEngine.getAllSystemUser()));
        }

        [HttpPost] 
        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            ViewData["Location"] = DisplayContentEngine.getLocationList();
            ViewData["Branch"] = DisplayContentEngine.getBranchList();
            //var v = ViewData.Model = UserListEngine.getAllSystemUser();
            var user = new SysUserList();

            return View(user);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(SysUserList user)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    //Save Registration
                    db.SysUserLists.AddObject(user);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(user);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }

        }

        public ActionResult Edit(string username)
        {
            SysUserList sysuserlist = db.SysUserLists.Single(s => s.UserName == username);
            return View(sysuserlist);

        }
    }
}
```

This controller that is called

### Create View

```
@model SmartTrack.Web.DAL.SysUserList

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="cuscreate">
        <fieldset>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>First Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>User Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Password</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.userPwd)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Location</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @(Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
                    .Name("ddLocation")
                    .BindTo((IEnumerable<DropDownItem>)ViewData["Location"])
                    .CascadeTo("ddlBranch")
                    )
                </td>
                <td>
                     <label>Branch</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @(Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
                    .Name("ddlBranch")
                    .BindTo((IEnumerable<DropDownItem>)ViewData["Branch"])
                    )
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>


        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

When the add button is click nothing happen can someone tell my whats my issue?

Thanks in advance

Regards
Kurt

Comment: try running firebug in chrome or firefox - check the console to see the data sent and/or errors

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see the form tags in your html that could be the reason where it does not know where to post

The view with action link Create New and the telerik grid does not have form tags in it

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a **data** element in your ajax request, so you are POSTing nothing.

If you want to get the data from the form you can just use .serialize():

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    url: '@Url.Action("Create","User")',
    success: function (result) {
        $('#cuscreate').html(result)
    }
});
```

Keep in mind, this will **only** work if its the only  on the page, otherwise you should use another selector, but you get the idea.

**UPDATE** from HatSoft's answer (upvote it!):

generally inside your  tags you should have  tags, to do that in MVC:

```
<fieldset>
    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p>your form</p>
    }
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What would be the data element i would place there?

Comment: I have done all the suggestions given but still not getting the desired result

Comment: Have you tried running firebug to see what your request is doing (if anything)

Comment: I am not getting an error it just that the page is not refreshing with the page that was called

Comment: from firebug the response shows thats its calling the correct view. But as i said before page does not refresh to display UI

Comment: You suggested to use another selector how would i go about doing this? Can you provide me with a example? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you cancel the default action of the submit button by returning false from your click handler in order to give your AJAX call chance to execute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "User")',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#cuscreate').html(result)
                }
            });
        });

        return false; // <!-- That's the important bit
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have done all the suggestions given but still not getting the desired result

Answer (score 0):

In correcting my problem I had to modify my index view to include div id = cuscreate which resulted in the CreateUser view displaying

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<div id="cuscreate" align="center">
 <fieldset>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />


      @using (Html.BeginForm())
      {
        //@{

        @(Html.Telerik().Grid<SmartTrack.Web.DAL.SysUserList>()
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("Index", "User"))
        .Name("UserList")
        .DataKeys(keys => keys
            .Add(c => c.UserName)
            .RouteKey("UserName"))
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.UserName).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(o => o.FirstName).Width(200);
            columns.Bound(o => o.LastName).Width(250);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Active).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled' name='Active' <#=Active? checked='checked' : '' #> />").Width(70).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }); ;


        })
        .Pageable(pagerAction => pagerAction.PageSize(20))
        .Sortable()
        .Selectable()
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Filterable()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:50%;" })
       )}


 </fieldset>  
       <br/>
       <div align="center">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="btnAdd" type="submit" style="height:40px;width:70px" ">Add</button>
            </td>
            <td>
            <button style="height:40px;width:70px" ">Edit</button>
            </td>
            <td>
            <button style="height:40px;width:70px" ">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>   
       </div>
  </div>     



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    url: '@Url.Action("CreateUser", "User")',
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#cuscreate').html(result)
                    }
                });
            });

            return false; // <!-- That's the important bit 
        }); 
</script>
```

Thanks for your assistance was really appreciated

Regards
Kurt